# How do I rename a file in Perforce, then add another file with the old name of the first file?

Tags: version-control, perforce, file-rename

Let's say that I have a file A.txt. I want to rename it to B.txt. I execute

```
p4 add A.txt
p4 rename A.txt B.txt
```

I would now like to add a *new* file A.txt in the same changelist.

When I execute

```
p4 add A.txt
```

I get the error message

```
A.txt - can't add (already opened for move/delete)
A.txt - warning: add of existing file
```

Is there a workaround to achieve my desired behavior. Otherwise, I will proceed with copying the original contents of A.txt to B.txt and modifying A.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Perforce's data model doesn't (currently) support the concept of a single revision both deleting a file and re-adding it (logically a *different* file with the same name) as a single atomic action.  A revision can have an action of `add`, or `delete` (in this case `move/delete`), but a single revision can't have an action of `delete, then add`; you need two consecutive revisions (in two different changelists) to represent those two actions.

If all possible, I would recommend splitting this sequence of actions into two changelists; "squashing" them as you describe will lose the information that B.txt is actually a renamed variant of A.txt, and if you ever need to merge either file, you'll have changes from one trying to merge into the other.  (If you know for certain you'll never need to merge these files, i.e. they're not branched anywhere and you don't have anyone else working on them concurrently, it doesn't really matter.)